# A simple case of struct, but getting a "bad char" error

Tags: python, struct

I'm attempting to read a section of a binary file, and decode it as a string of characters using the struct. module.

It's a simple enough case. Here is the bytes argument:

```
b'11:10:00\x00ng '
```

and here is the function I am attempting to use:

```
struct.unpack('utf-8', b'11:10:00\x00ng ')
```

The output should be twelve characters, no?:

```
'11:10:00 ng '
```

It returns `"struct.error bad char in struct format"` for some reason. What's going on? I tried a lot of resources but nobody had an example of this happening. I've tried other formats besides `'utf-8'`, such as `'ascii'`.

edit - there seems to be confusion; maybe i should have given my problem in less general terms:

I am attempting to write a command that will decode a bytes object created using f.read, in a variable format, and I tried to do it this way:

Value = struct.unpack(Format, Bytes)[0]

where
Bytes = f.read(Length)
and
Format = 'i' 
or 'd' or whatever it needs to be.

What I tried worked great for the case of an integer ('i') but did not work for the case of a string of characters - I got the error instead, and I'm trying to figure out why. Thanks for any help!

edit2 - for anyone coming after me, it looks like this is simply not possible to handle in python with a single function, because the struct.unpack function doesn't handle unicode strings and the decode. function doesn't handle encoded numbers. The only way to do what I need to do appears to be to use an if: to apply the proper function for the format

Comment: `struct.unpack('utf-8', ...` - hold on. What the heck do you think `struct.unpack` does?

Comment: for example, struct.unpack('i', b'+\r\x00\x00') unpacks the bytes object as an integer, 3371.

Comment: in this case, however, I need to unpack it as ascii characters. I don't understand what you're getting at.

Answer (score 1):

## EDIT

1. no `"i"` is not a valid encoding to use `str.decode`

   - see https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings
2. no `"utf-8"` is not a valid format string to pass to `struct.unpack`

   - see https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters

## old anser ...

`struct.unpack` is not the right tool to use here

```
b'11:10:00\x00ng '.decode("utf8")
b'+\r\x00\x00'.decode("utf8")
```

you simply want to decode the bytes to a unicode string I believe

if you want to `struct.unpack` a string you can ... but its just unpacking a bytestring

```
fmt = "bb5s" #2 bytes and a string of length 5
struct.unpack(fmt,b"\x00\x12\x33\x43\x55\x77\x65")

#result: (0, 18, b'3CUwe')
```

Comment: the thing is, that won't work for the example of b'+\r\x00\x00' which is in the integer format. I get the error "unknown encoding 'i'"

Comment: what? you make no sense ... thats not the string you showed and there is no encoding i involved... http://ideone.com/29Pn3B

Comment: see my edit - I have an arbitrary bytes string encoded in a variable fashion, and I need a single line which can handle the case of a string of characters, like  b'11:10:00\x00ng ', or also an integer, like b'+\r\x00\x00'

Comment: @Nate you're asking for two different things, getting a string from bytes and getting an int from bytes. The procedures for the two are very different. You aren't going to get a single statement that can handle them interchangeably.

Comment: It could be that there just isn't that functionality in the struct. module, but I wouldn't know!

Comment: So, the answer is essentially that what I want isn't possible? I would really rather not handle this with a variety of "if" statements because it seems inelegant, but I can if I have to. Sorry for taking up your time.

Comment: what are you talking about .... ? you can do (almost) anything very elegantly ... it is not clear to me yet what the problem is with decode ..

Comment: Are you sure it works fine? I tried b'+\r\x00\x00'.decode('i') and it definitely did not work. If it did, I wouldn't need the struct module at all. Essentially the formats I may encounter are doubles, integers, floats, and unicode strings. I'd like a single function that could decode a bytestring into any one of those but I'm not sure there is one anymore. I though struct.unpack was what I needed.

Comment: @Nate: You might need a multi-stage decoding process, one phase with `struct` to extract packed number types and bytestrings, then a second phase decoding the bytestrings in whatever codec they were originally encoded with. It's hard to tell.

Comment: @Nate `struct.unpack` works great for everything *except* strings. Besides, you're going to need that big `if` to figure out which format to pass to `unpack` anyway.

Comment: I already know which format to pass to unpack because in the file I am converting it is given as a code in an earlier address - that's why I thought I could do it with a single general function. However @user2357112 explains to me that it might be simply impossible.

Comment: its easy ... btu you have not provided enough info for anyone to really help you ... it sounds like you have given just enough info to get answers you already know about .... you should probably re-read the FAQ about how to write a good question that you will get good answers for ... it is not clear what is not working for you currently (yes you cannot `s.decode('i')` and no you cannot `struct.unpack("utf8",...)` but neither of those is really what your question is imho

Comment: Actually, both of those were exactly what my question was - I was trying to find out if I could struct.unpack("utf8",...) or if I could s.decode('i'). Thank you for your help!

Comment: ok i edited my answer to address your "actual" question of if you could do that specifically ...

Answer (score 1):

The struct module does a completely different job from what you're trying to do. It's for deserializing data that looks like serialized C structs (hence the name). `int`s, `double`s, fixed-size `char` arrays, things like that, packed together in a rigid layout with fixed alignment and padding. If you look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html), you'll see nothing related to Unicode codecs, and the format string argument format looks nothing like a codec name.

You want the built-in bytestring `decode` method, which does Unicode decoding:

```
b'11:10:00\x00ng '.decode('utf-8')
```

though that `\x00` will still be a Unicode NUL, not a space, because Unicode doesn't work like that.

Comment: So, am I right in saying that I simply can't handle the cases I am trying to handle with a single function? struct.unpack works fine for integer/float formats, I know, but it doesn't work with unicode strings.

decode on the other hand doesn't work with integers etc, but will decode strings. I know what they are for, I was just trying to find a way to handle all of these cases without if/then loops.

Comment: @Nate: Unicode encoding/decoding is simply not part of the task the `struct` module was designed for. It was designed for structs.

Comment: thank you. i'm a chemist, not a programmer, and so my fundamentals are pretty weak. I wouldn't have known what a struct is, or the difference between 'i' and 'utf8' as formats for a bytestring. I'm actually only doing this to decode a proprietary format for IR spectra, but I'm having success so far.